How to automate Office Word from a .Net 8 C# Console application
I am trying to automate Office Word from a .Net 8 Console application.
This is my code:
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        var appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    }
}

This is how my .csproj file looks like:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word">
      <HintPath>C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>   
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

When I try to run my application in Debug mode from inside VS I get the following error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. The system cannot find the file
specified.'

I cannot understand why I get this error. I have explicitly added the file using a COM Reference, as can be seen from the .csproj file. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

We see you have the interop assembly referenced but have you the correct office version backing the interop assembly installed? FileNotFoundException might not necessarily be about the file mentioned in the exception but in the loading of an assembly scenario a dependency of that thing.

@Ralf I currently have Word 2019 installed. Isn't this the correct version?

Don't know haven't done office interop in a long time. But i know that at least the VSTO stuff (if that is the source of the interop assembly) was very picky about the concrete version. The interop assemblies where office version dependent.

Have you read the notices here in the docs? It reads as if you shouldn't use the COM interop stuff in anything else but the old Net Framework.

.NET 8 is .NET Core 8. It can't use .NET Framework libraries or the GAC. The net8.0 is the cross-platform target.

Check the COM Interop docs for .NET 6 and later and the ComWrappers tutorial

When I browse for word in the references (as You apparently are doing), I get the same content in the project file.
BUT if I locate word using the COM reference I get another content in ItemGroup:
  <ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word">
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <VersionMinor>7</VersionMinor>
      <VersionMajor>8</VersionMajor>
      <Guid>00020905-0000-0000-c000-000000000046</Guid>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <Isolated>false</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>true</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>

THIS runs without errors on my computer (the other version does return the same error as yours).
This is how my COMreference selector looks:

By the way: remember that the code actually starts a (hidden) version of Word!

If I type Word on the Search box of the Reference Manager window nothing appears on my end.

This option is unfortunately not available on my Reference Manager window. You have tried using this library from a .NET 8 application and it works?

I've used a the Console application template, using .Net 8.

Thanks a lot, working fine now! I had to delete a folder from the registry to make the Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library appear. [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/microsoft-word-object-library-160-missing-with-off/1201411]

I followed following instruction: If there are two values under the path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\TypeLib{00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\8.7 delete the folder Win32.
